# Validation of DateTime string with timeOffset in Javascrtip

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I want to test if an ISO Timestamp is valid by using this little function:

```
function isValidDateTime = function (datetime) {
    return !isNaN(new Date(datetime).getTime());
}
```

Works like a charm for *2012-12-31T12:00:00*.

However, some of the strings have an offset like that, and this is not working with Date() in Javascript: *2012-12-31T12:00:00+01*.

Hence I adjusted my function like that:

```
function isValidDateTime(datetime) {
    // Javascript's date does not like offsets ...
    datetime = datetime.replace('/\+[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}/', '');
    return !isNaN(new Date(datetime).getTime());
}
```

The regexp is correct (http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C%2B%5B0-2%5D%7B1%7D%5B0-9%5D%7B1%7D&input=2012-12-31T12%3A00%3A00%2B01) and I have tried in PHP with preg_replace - works.

Why not in JS?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `'`:

```
datetime = datetime.replace(/\+[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}/, '');
```